# How to get the maximum available screen height in java script?

Tags: javascript, css

`document`/`window` `outerHeight` provides the size of the window (e.g when the browser windows is re-sized the value changes ).

`screen.availHeight` gives you the actual screen size (including the actual browser navigation etc)

I tried creating a fixed div set with `top:0,buttom:0` and get the `outerHeight` but it's also restricted to the window's current size.

What is the best way to get the max available height when the window is maximized ?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The answer, provided with the help of @Greg Burghardt is

```
screen.availHeight - (window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight)
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_screen.asp

Comment: Couldn't you just set the div's height and width to 100%?

Comment: @Juhana I'm using a control that requires explicit height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for:

```
document.documentElement.offset[Height|Width]
```

A good reference: [A Tale of Two Viewports](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html)